# How to get latitude and longitude from Model into my url link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, openweathermap

I am trying to get city weather in current location. I have model, where is getting weather data from JSON, and also I have model, where I am getting my location (latitude and longitude). But I don't know, how I can get this latitude and longitude in my link.

**WeatherModel:** where I use url link. I want use latitude and longitude from my LocationModel below

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

protocol IWeatherService {
    
    func getCitiesWeather(forCoordinates coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (Result<CitiesWeather, Error>) -> Void)
}

enum WeatherServiceError: Error {
    case badUrl
}

final class WeatherService: IWeatherService {
     
    func weatherURLString(forCoordinates coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> String {
       return "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(coordinates.latitude)&lon=\(coordinates.longitude)&units=metric&appid=b382e4a70dfb690b16b9381daac545ac&lang=ru"
    }
    
    func getCitiesWeather(forCoordinates coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (Result<CitiesWeather, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        //weatherURLString(forCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) ???
        
        //LocationManager.shared.locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations: [CLLocation]) ???
        
        //Проверка, что у нас есть url адрес
        guard let url = URL(string: .url) else {
            return completion(.failure(WeatherServiceError.badUrl))
        }
            
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(CitiesWeather.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(result))
            }
            catch {
                print("failed to convert \(error)")
            }
        
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

**LocationModel:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

protocol ILocationService {
    
    func getUserLocation(completion: @escaping ((CLLocation) -> Void))
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, ILocationService, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    static let shared = LocationManager()
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    
    public func getUserLocation(completion: @escaping ((CLLocation) -> Void)) {
        self.completion = completion
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    public func resolveLocationName(with location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping ((String?) -> Void)) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: .current) { placemarks, error in
            guard let place = placemarks?.first, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            print(location)
            
            var name = ""
            
            if let locality = place.locality {
                name += locality
            }
            
            if let adminRegion = place.administrativeArea {
                name += ", \(adminRegion)"
            }
            
            completion(name)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        completion?(location)
        
        //Эти значения надо передать в WeatherService
        print(location.coordinate.latitude)
        print(location.coordinate.longitude)
        
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    var completion: ((CLLocation) -> Void)?
}
```

Comment: The static `static let url` makes no sense. First call the Location manager to get the location. In the completion handler build the URL and call the weather service

Comment: @vadian thank you for the answer! Can you tell more detail about how to call weather service in the completion handler?

Answer (score 0):

As vadian said in his comment, this bit can't work:

```
private extension String {
    
    static let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(coordinates.latitude)&lon=\(coordinates.longitude)&units=metric&appid=b382e4a70dfb690b16b9381daac545ac&lang=ru"
}
```

You should create a function that takes coordinates and returns a URL string for a weather update:

```
func weatherURLString(forCoordinates coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
   return "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(coordinates.latitude)&lon=\(coordinates.longitude)&units=metric&appid=b382e4a70dfb690b16b9381daac545ac&lang=ru"
```

Rewrite your `getCitiesWeather()` function to take a parameter `coordinates` of type CLLocationCoordinate2D, and have it call the above function to generate the URL string it will use.

You have code that asks to update the user's location, and implements the `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` function. In your `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` function, you call a completion handler. Have that completion handler call the weather service with the user's updated location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I need more details. I created a function, how you said and rewrite `getCitiesWeather()`, but I don't understand about `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` I update my code, could you please check?